# How to launch N times a script Pig using oozie?

Tags: hadoop, workflow, apache-pig, oozie

I need to process a lot of files with some specifically date. I find only one solution, which is to launch a job N times with each time a different dataset. The partitions used is based on yyyy, mm, dd. I have a java action which generate the good partition to use for each data.

My question is, how can I create a loop to launch my script N times ? I work today with oozie workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for [coordinators](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html).

You can declare [Datasets](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5._Dataset) and let oozie automatically start a workflow when a specfic dataset instance is available.

Comment: This. Declare the data set by describing a URI containing year, month and day and give it a frequency (e.g. 1 day). Then you can start your pig job with one or more instances of this data set as input. This allows you for example to use the last x instances as input by specifying the start instance (${coord:current(-10)}) and the end instance (${coord:current(0)}).